# Python code integration in R: works while development but not after release

Tags: r, rpython

I am developing a R package on RStudio platform. I have many functions written in python which I want to call using R. For now I just implemented a simple reverse complement function for a DNA sequence. While writing and building the project on RStudio, the code works fine. Once I release it on github and install on other machine from the repo, it successfully installs, but when I call the function it fails to run. The details are shown below:

$ cat rev.py

```
def revcompl (s):
    rev_s = ''.join([{'M':'M', 'A':'T','C':'G','G':'C','T':'A'}[B] for B in s][::-1]).replace ("CM","MG")
    return rev_s
```

$ cat reverse_complement.R

```
#' Reverse complement for a given DNA sequence
#'
#' \code{reverse_complement} Reverse complement of a DNA sequence
#'
#' @usage reverse_complement (sequence)
#'
#' @param sequence A DNA sequence
#' @export
#'

reverse_complement <- function(sequence) {
    revFile = system.file("python", "rev.py", package = "rpytrial")
    print (revFile)
    python.load(revFile)
    rev_strand = python.call ("revcompl", sequence)
    return (rev_strand)
}
```

After doing install_github, when I run reverse_complement("AAAAA"), I get the following error:

```
 [1] ""
   File "<string>", line 3
     except Exception as e:_r_error = e.__str__()
          ^
 IndentationError: expected an indented block
 Error in python.exec(python.command) : name 'revcompl' is not defined
 In addition: Warning message:
 In file(con, "r") :
   file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

From the error I can say that it is not finding the path. But is there a way to fix it?

Thanks, 
Satya

Comment: Please post your full Python code including the `def revcompl():` lines. Python is a strong type language requiring syntax rules especially in indentation of functions and loops.

Comment: @Parfait: I have edited the python code now. Thank you for correcting me. I am going to implement this in my code too. But I do not thing this is going to solve my problem

Comment: is your python file located at `inst/python/rev.py` in your directory structure?

Comment: No, the code is located in a directory named python which is Project's home directory. Basically **R**, **inst** and **python** are in same directory. I'll try moving it to `inst`. Even if it works, I would prefer the python directory to be in project's home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** move your `python` directory to `inst/python`.

In order for additional files to be installed the package, and found by `system.file()`, you have to have them within the `inst` directory, *or* in one of the other specific directories mandated by the *Writing R Extensions* document.

From the [Non-R scripts in packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Non_002dR-scripts-in-packages) of *Writing R Extensions*:

> Subdirectory `exec` could be used for scripts for interpreters such as the shell, BUGS, JavaScript, Matlab, Perl, php (amap), Python or Tcl (Simile), or even R. However, it seems more common to use the `inst` directory, for example `WriteXLS/inst/Perl`, `NMF/inst/m-files`, `RnavGraph/inst/tcl`, `RProtoBuf/inst/python` and `emdbook/inst/BUGS` and `gridSVG/inst/js`.

Also see the [Package subdirectories](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) section.

So if you want your python code to be found via `system.file("python", "rev.py", package = "rpytrial")` it *must* be in `inst/python/rev.py`.  I think putting it in `exec/rev.py` and using `system.file("exec", "rev.py", package = "rpytrial")` would also be an option (although I've never tried that approach).

If you have strong feelings about having the `python/` directory directly within the package's 'head' directory while developing, you could write a custom build script that (1) makes a copy of the whole package directory; (2) moves `python` to `inst/python`; and (3) builds the package from the copied directory (I can't see how to make this work via `devtools::install_github()`, though).

Comment: It worked :), Ben. Thank you so much for your suggestion. I was dumb though.

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.